# Combine Redux (fetch userinfo) with React-Router (private routes + pass userinfo as props to routes)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, passport.js, react-router-v4

I am struggling to determine the best way to handle authentication in my React / React-Router / Redux / MERN-stack application, and any help is appreciated. In particular, I am not weaving the various libraries together all that well, and the result is that I am handling checking-if-a-user-is-logged-in at the individual component levels, whereas I think this should be done in App.js.

My application uses passport.js for auth, and my mongodb has a `users` collection that keeps track of each user's info. A document in the `users` collection looks like this:

[image]

My app has a redux action `userActions` that uses the `authorizedReducer` to add to the reduxState the objects one or more of `userInfo, authorized, loading`. `loading` simply returns TRUE/FALSE depending on whether the action is complete, `authorized` returns a TRUE/FALSE boolean as to whether or not the logged in, *if authorized == TRUE*, then `userInfo` returns the user's info from its mongodb document (otherwise no `userInfo` is returned).

With all of that said, he's how my App.js and index.js files are currently structured:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppNavbar from './components//Navbars/AppNavbar';
import LoginModal from './components/LoginModal';
import SignupModal from './components/SignupModal';
import HomePage from './path-to-component';
import AboutUs from './path-to-component';
import HelpPage from './path-to-component';
import NoMatch from './path-to-nomatch';
... import of ~15 other routes ...

// Want to use this redux userAction to get info on the user (if he's logged in, other acct info, etc.)
import { userActions } from '../../../actions/auth/auth-actions.js'; 

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleShowLogin = this.handleShowLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseLogin = this.handleCloseLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleShowSignup = this.handleShowSignup.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseSignup = this.handleCloseSignup.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            showLogin: false,
            showSignup: false
        };
    }

    // dont worry about these - just used for displaying login / signup modals
    handleCloseLogin() { this.setState({ showLogin: false }); }
    handleShowLogin() { this.setState({ showLogin: true }); }
    handleCloseSignup() { this.setState({ showSignup: false }); }
    handleShowSignup() { this.setState({ showSignup: true }); }

    // want to be able to do 1-time grab of user actions, storing the user's info in reduxstate    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.authorize());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <AppNavbar login={this.handleShowLogin} signup={this.handleShowSignup} />
                <LoginModal close={this.handleCloseLogin} showLogin={this.state.showLogin} signup={this.handleShowSignup} />
                <SignupModal close={this.handleCloseSignup} showSignup={this.state.showSignup} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/about' render={(props) => <AboutUs {...props} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/site-guide' render={(props) => <HelpPage />} />
                    ... ~15 more routes ...
                    <Route component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch>
                <AppFooter />
                <TableHeaderTooltip/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

// want to have this here to grab userInfo & authorized, but this doesnt work in App.js
function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    return {
        userInfo: reduxState.authorizedReducer.userInfo,
        authorized: reduxState.authorizedReducer.authorized,
        loading: reduxState.authorizedReducer.loading
     };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**Index.js**

```
import store from './store';
... other imports ...

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

In short, the above App.js does not work as intended. The userInfo and authorized do not work, and I wonder if redux data-fetching cannot be done in the App.js file.

**In summary**, being able to grab auth info (is a user logged in, and if so, whats the users info) in main App.js file would be great. I want to pass the `authorizedReducer.authorized` boolean, and the `userInfo` object, as props into routes. Instead, currently I am calling userActions() to get userInfo/auth info, but this is being called in each component that needs this info (eg. HomePage and About, but also many of my apps routes that are excluded above (...) need userInfo and authorized info).

Is this possible? Am I moving along the right track, or should I go in some other direction? Any help with this is **super greatly appreciated!!**

**EDIT:** if this helps - this is what my reduxState looks like w.r.t. the relevant reducers for auth. I have an `authentication` reducer that checks for login, and then the `authorizedReducer` reducer that also checks for login, and also has the userInfo.

[image]

**EDIT2:** to clarify, the `authentication` reducer populates with TRUE automatically when a user is logged in, which is great. However, the `userInfo` and `authorized` from `authorizedReducer` only populates when the `userActions()` action is dispatched.

Comment: It's definitely possible, you can perform any redux action nested within the <Provider> component you've shown above.  Where exactly are you trying to access the userInfo and authorized props in the component?

Comment: Im not sure why the action / reducer did not work in App.js previously for me then, given that its possible.

Comment: "Where exactly are you trying to access the userInfo and authorized props in the component?" -

I'm simply trying to fetch the userInfo and authorized prop from App.js, so that each of the Route components doesn't have to make their own userActions() call

Comment: Is that dispatch hitting your reducer?  If you throw in a breakpoint, or `console.log` statement?  If so, you know for sure it's working, just a matter of why the data isn't wiring over

Comment: I can check. I will note that changing the bottom of App.js (mapStateToProps, and connect) breaks the entire routing of the app. Clicking links to navigate to different routes **does** update the url but **doesnt** change the page / rerender the page, so i get stuck at homepage.

Comment: this is what generated my original concern that redux and `mapStateToProps` simply couldnt be used in App.js

Comment: the fetch itself, however, does appear to work yes.

Comment: Alright, so technically it looks like you already have access in your App.js, since the dispatch is working, you have access to the redux store there, and the mapped state as well.  Inside your App.js, check out `this.props` in the render method, you should have `userInfo, authenticated, and loading` properties

Comment: Yep those are there in props, so the fetch is working. I guess I should be asking then why doesnt the app rerender when I click different links, which should lead to different routes. The URLs update but the pages themselves to not update / rerender...